# Google Sheets - sumif using condition on row and column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet that looks like the following

TABLE 1

```
ID/Month | May | June | July | August | September | October

ID101    | 30  | 50   | 50   | 80     | 20        | 60

ID201    | 20  | 30   | 10   | 40     | 30        | 50

ID101    | 10  | 50   | 60   | 80     | 70        | 20

ID301    | 20  | 80   | 70   | 40     | 40        | 70

ID101    | 30  | 70   | 80   | 50     | 90        | 50

ID301    | 80  | 20   | 30   | 20     | 60        | 20
```

TABLE 2

```
ID    | Date      | Value

ID101 | July      | ?

ID201 | September | ?

ID301 | June      | ?
```

**? is the sum of the values in TABLE 1 if the IDs matches, and if the row of dates are less than or equal to the dates specified in TABLE 2**.

So

- for `ID101 | July | ?`  I need to find the sum of values in row `ID101` in TABLE 1 and May/June/July columns
- for `ID201 | September | ?` I need to find the sum of values in row `ID201` in TABLE 1 and May/June/July/August/September columns

How do I do a sumif like an index match table where I can look up conditions in column (IDs) and rows (less than or equal to *dates*)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J2=$A$2:$A$7)*(MONTH(K2&1)>=MONTH($B$1:$G$1&1))*$B$2:$G$7)
```

[image]

To convert your month names to correct number using `MONTH(K2&1)` formula you must specify a `United States` locale in the spreadsheet settings

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do three things:

- Un-pivot your table ("wide" to "long") so that each value is in its own row, identified by an ID and a Month (this is a little tricky)
- Give your month a numeric value (the MONTH() function comes in handy)
- Use SUMIFS to check the ID column and the Month column.

Here's a working sample: [Google Sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ClxhdWhCnsfimsXRQ55sXwkrxTIxY1pufMe_FxsRA8/)